# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1120,1472,4) into shape (3000,3000)

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, image-processing, array-broadcasting

I have an image with shape (1120,1472,4), am trying change this to (3000, 3000, 4) the code i have written is like this.

```
pad_shape = (3000, 3000)
i = np.array('test.tif')
result = np.zeros(pad_shape,dtype=int)
result[:i.shape[0], :i.shape[1]] = i
print(result)
```

It generates

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1120, 1472, 4) into shape (3000, 3000)
```

Comment: 1120*1472 != 3000*3000, so what do you mean by "change the shape" ? There would be more elements in your new array, what would they be ?

Comment: This is a simple typo, you missed a 4 in pad_shape

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import dtype

pad_shape = np.array((3000, 3000, 4))
i = np.zeros((1120, 1472, 4), dtype=np.int)

result = np.zeros(pad_shape, dtype=np.int)

x, y = 10, 10
shape = i.shape
print shape

rr = result[y:y+shape[0], x:x+shape[1]]
print rr
```

The x and y variables are for padding. The error you received because of padding.

Comment: The error received was because OP missed a 4 in result shape.

Comment: But be careful to for x and y variables. If you cross the bound of the image then you will get that error again.

Comment: The error definitely about the boundary of the image not OP. If you test my code you will see P.Camilleri

Comment: P.Camilleri after adding 4 on pad_shape code works. Thanks both of you

Comment: No, the error comes from the missing 4 in pad_shape. 
 
The x and y variables are useless, this answer is misleading.

Comment: Yes but I fixed already it in my code. The main problem here boundary and He did not recognize about it but with this code everthing is more clear.

Comment: The main problem here is not the boundary, you can remove the x and y lines and just do results[:shape[0], :shape[1]] = i

Comment: Kewin Rather thanks for your help, I understood the issue but what is the role of x, y  i didn't understood

Comment: The x and y are the padding variables for your image. Apply it to your code and see what is going on.

Comment: @AnupPanwar these variables are not necessary ! result[:shape[0], :shape[1]] = i is enough if you change your pad shape to (3000, 3000, 4)

Comment: İt is not important to solve the current problem it is important to solve current and future problems.   Thats what ı do.

Comment: @KewinRather How are you solving a problem? You are creating one adding 2 useless variables!

Comment: Do you know What variables are doing ? Of course no. With these two variables the image inside the other image can be move through the main image boundary. This is a very useful feature cause he can maybe want to to this in the future. Did you know understand what I mean ????